# Android GCM message not received on device

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I have tried to set up my app to receive push notifications. The problem however is that although they are sent successfully from the server they don't arrive to the device.

Here is my code:

### Manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<!-- Keeps the processor from sleeping when a message is received. -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />

<permission android:name="com.jampez.smalltalk.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" 
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.jampez.smalltalk.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />

<!-- This app has permission to register and receive data message. -->
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />

<!-- Network State Permissions to detect Internet status -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

<activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

      <receiver
        android:name="com.google.android.gcm.GCMBroadcastReceiver"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
        <intent-filter>

            <!-- Receives the actual messages. -->
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <!-- Receives the registration id. -->
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
            <action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE" />

            <category android:name="com.jampez.smalltalk" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

### GCMIntentService.java

This is in the main package with the rest of the activities

```
public class GCMIntentService extends GCMBaseIntentService {
private static final String TAG = "GCMIntentService";

public GCMIntentService() {
    super(SENDER_ID);
}

/**
 * Method called on device registered
 **/
@Override
protected void onRegistered(Context context, String registrationId) {
    Log.i(TAG, "Device registered: regId = " + registrationId);
    displayMessage(context, "Your device registred with GCM");
    ServerUtilities.register(context, registrationId);
}

/**
 * Method called on device un registred
 * */
@Override
protected void onUnregistered(Context context, String registrationId) {
    Log.i(TAG, "Device unregistered");
    displayMessage(context, getString(R.string.gcm_unregistered));
    ServerUtilities.unregister(context, registrationId);
}

/**
 * Method called on Receiving a new message
 * */
@Override
protected void onMessage(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Log.i(TAG, "Received message");
    String message = intent.getExtras().getString("message");

    displayMessage(context, message);
    // notifies user
    generateNotification(context, null, message, (long) 01);
}

/**
 * Method called on receiving a deleted message
 * */
@Override
protected void onDeletedMessages(Context context, int total) {
    Log.i(TAG, "Received deleted messages notification");
    String message = getString(R.string.gcm_deleted, total);
    displayMessage(context, message);
    // notifies user
    generateNotification(context, null, message, (long) 00);
}

/**
 * Method called on Error
 * */
@Override
public void onError(Context context, String errorId) {
    Log.i(TAG, "Received error: " + errorId);
    displayMessage(context, getString(R.string.gcm_error, errorId));
}

@Override
protected boolean onRecoverableError(Context context, String errorId) {
    // log message
    Log.i(TAG, "Received recoverable error: " + errorId);
    displayMessage(context, getString(R.string.gcm_recoverable_error,
            errorId));
    return super.onRecoverableError(context, errorId);
}

/**
 * Issues a notification to inform the user that server has sent a message.
 */
private static void generateNotification(Context context, String title, String message, Long extra) {
    int icon = R.drawable.ic_launcher;

    Integer i = (int) (long) extra;

    if(title == null){
     title = context.getString(R.string.app_name);
    }

    Intent notificationIntent  = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);

    PendingIntent Int = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, i, notificationIntent, 0);
    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
            .setSmallIcon(icon)
            .setContentTitle(title)
            .setContentIntent(Int)
            .setContentText(message)
            .setAutoCancel(true) 
            .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND | Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE | Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS);
        NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        mNotificationManager.notify(i, mBuilder.build());


}
}
```

### AppConfig.java

```
public static final String DISPLAY_MESSAGE_ACTION = "com.jampez.smalltalk.DISPLAY_MESSAGE";

public static final String TAG = "GCM";

static final String EXTRA_MESSAGE = "message";

/**
 * Notifies UI to display a message.
 * <p>
 * This method is defined in the common helper because it's used both by
 * the UI and the background service.
 *
 * @param context application's context.
 * @param message message to be displayed.
 */
public static void displayMessage(Context context, String message) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(DISPLAY_MESSAGE_ACTION);
    intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, message);
    context.sendBroadcast(intent);
}
```

### ServerUtilities.java

```
public final class ServerUtilities {
private static final int MAX_ATTEMPTS = 5;

/**
 * Register this account/device pair within the server.
 *
 */
public static void register(final Context context, final String regId) {
    Log.i(TAG, "registering device (regId = " + regId + ")");


    // Once GCM returns a registration id, we need to register on our server
    // As the server might be down, we will retry it a couple
    // times.
    for (int i = 1; i <= MAX_ATTEMPTS;) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Attempt #" + i + " to register");
        displayMessage(context, context.getString(R.string.server_registering, i, MAX_ATTEMPTS));
        GCMRegistrar.setRegisteredOnServer(context, true);
        String message = context.getString(R.string.server_registered);
        AppConfig.displayMessage(context, message);
        return;
    }
    String message = context.getString(R.string.server_register_error,
            MAX_ATTEMPTS);
    AppConfig.displayMessage(context, message);
}

/**
 * Unregister this account/device pair within the server.
 */
public static void unregister(final Context context, final String regId) {
    Log.i(TAG, "unregistering device (regId = " + regId + ")");
    Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
    params.put("regId", regId);
    //post(serverUrl, params);
    GCMRegistrar.setRegisteredOnServer(context, false);
    String message = context.getString(R.string.server_unregistered);
    AppConfig.displayMessage(context, message);
}

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if this is the main reason or not, but you are missing a permission. Because GCM requires a Google account, you should declare the following permission too:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
```

Also, declare a `service` too:

```
<service android:name=".GCMIntentService" />
```

EDIT:

If your error still persists, try this:

Go to Project/Properties/Java Build Path/Order and Export -- Make sure there's a check in front of Android Dependencies and the support library, if you use it. Mark all checkboxes. Click on Apply and clean the project.

Comment: I've added the permission, It's now producing this error in the LogCat http://imgur.com/6ksaP9q any ideas?

Comment: I was just typing to say that the error is still there when your answer updated, needless to say that it now works perfectly. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

GCM register() has been deprecated, and it is recommended to use InstanceID to perform general GCM registration management.

Please try [this](https://developers.google.com/instance-id/)

Sample implementation is [here](https://github.com/google/gcm)